# Is Alice also immune to undead's bite?

Tags: plot-explanation, resident-evil

In the Resident Evil movie series, it states that Alice is infected with the virus, and is the only one who was able to bind with the virus in a cellular level. So, it seems like the T-Virus doesn't kill her.

The question is, is she immune even to undead bites? What if one of the mutated creatures bites her ( Such as the one that left a scratch on Matt and turned him into Nemesis )? Does the T-Virus mutate Alice again?

The movie doesn't include a scene of her being bit, so I don't really know what happens if she is.

Comment: Alice is immune to the t-virus, getting bitten or scratched by a creature that carries the t-virus would likely not have any effect, she’s immune right?

Comment: I'm not sure. Does the T-Virus itself evolve over time? Isn't it different to be infected directly by the virus itself, or by a mutated creature?

Comment: It's mentioned that Alice is immune to T-virus right? So she won't get infected from it. means there will be mostly no effect from undead's bite. And in above comment you said that T-virus is evolving. yes that's true. but consider the base for the movie. **Aliice will have no effect whatsoever from the virus**, So I think Alice has immune system that however evolves along with the virus and keep her from getting infected

Comment: Alice is already infected with virus and that virus gave her superpowers. I don't think infecting her again will effect at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alice is immune to further T-virus mutation from bites

As mentioned, Alice is already infected with the T-virus. More so, she has demonstrated a very unique ability to adapt to the virus.

It is worth clarifying that, while Matt did get infected by a scratch, he is captured by a group of Umbrella agents who make mention of using Matt in the NEMESIS program. We are left to assume the rest, but it is heavily implied that further intervention through this NEMESIS program mutates Matt into the NEMESIS tyrant.

It might also be fair to assume that the NEMESIS tyrant is created in a similar way to the same tyrant of the video game franchise, where the subject undergoes further surgery and parasite infection, in order to create the mutation known as the NEMESIS tyrant. I.e., the initial T-virus infection only flags the subject for viability in the program. It does not turn them into the tyrant, by itself.